# How can I insert/update rows with C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am quit busy turning a old classic asp website to a .NET site. also i am now using SQL Server.

Now I have some old code

```
strsql = "select * FROM tabel WHERE ID = " & strID & " AND userid = " & struserid 
rs1.open strsql, strCon, 2, 3

if rs1.eof THEN
   rs1.addnew
end if

if straantal <> 0 THEN
   rs1("userid") = struserid
   rs1("verlangid") = strID
   rs1("aantal") = straantal
end if

rs1.update
rs1.close
```

I want to use this in SQL Server. The update way. How can I do this?

- How can I check if the datareader is EOF/EOL
- How can I insert a row id it is EOF/EOL
- How can I update a row or delete a row with one function?

Comment: Read about SqlDataAdapter or ADO.Net in general

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use raw SQL commands you can try something like this

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cnn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = cnn;

    // Example of reading with SqlDataReader
    cmd.CommandText = "select sql query here";

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            myList.Add((int)reader[0]);
        }
    }

    // Example of updating row
    cmd.CommandText = "update sql query here";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the method you use... Are you going to use Entity Framework and LINQ? Are you going to use a straight SQL Connection? I would highly recommend going down the EF route but a simple straight SQL snippet would look something like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string here"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM xyz ETC", connection))
    {                
        // Process results
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int userId = (int)reader["UserID"];
                string somethingElse = (string)reader["AnotherField"];
                // Etc, etc...
            }
        }
    }

    // To execute a query (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE etc)
    using (var commandExec = new SqlCommand("DELETE * FROM xyz ETC", connection))
    {
        commandExec.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You will note the various elements wrapped in **using**, that is because you need to release the memory / connection when you have finished. This should answer your question quickly but as others have suggested (including me) I would investigate Entity Framework as it is much more powerful but has a learning curve attached to it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL store procedure for  Update. And call this store procedure through C#.

Create procedure [dbo].[xyz_Update]
(
@para1
@para2
)
AS
BEGIN
    Update tablename
     Set Fieldname1=@para1,
     Set Feildname2=@para2

end